# ActionListener and KeyListener Error

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, keylistener, keyevent

I am making a class (called `Play`), that extends `JFrame`, and implements `ActionListener` and `KeyListener`. This class does not hold the `main()` method, because there is a different class for that.

I am getting an error which states, "Class `Play` must either be declared abstract, or implement abstract method `keyReleased(KeyEvent)` in `KeyListener`".

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

public class Play extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);
    double x = 0, y = 0, velx = 0, vely = 0;

    public Play() {
        timer.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40));
    }

    public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
        x += velx;
        y += vely;
    }

    public void up() {
        vely = -1.5;
        velx = 0;
    }

    public void down() {
        vely = 1.5;
        velx = 0;
    }

    public void left() {
        vely = 0;
        velx = -1.5;
    }

    public void right() {
        vely = 0;
        velx = 1.5;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up();
        }

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            down();
        }

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left();
        }

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right();
        }
    }

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by having a look at [What Is an Interface?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), [Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html), [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and  [How to Write a Key Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) and

Comment: And before you post you next question on my your `KeyListener` mysteriously stops working, take a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, do what it says. Since you're inheriting the KeyListener interface, you have to implement all of the interface's methods, including 'keyReleased'

Comment: I have tried that, but i still get the same error. I have updated the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

The KeyListener must have all of it's methods implemented.

Simply add this method to the class and it should work

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}
```

You must also `Override` all of the `KeyListener` implemented methods

Comment: I have tried that, but i still get the same error. I have updated the code in the question

Comment: @user3704212 try adding the `@Override` annotation before each of the implemented methods

Comment: I have tried adding Override annotation before each of the implemented methods, and it just creates an error on every line which has Override.

Comment: @user3704212, try renaming the `actionPreformed` to `actionPerformed` and see if that helps

Comment: I would also suggest `Overriding` **all** of the inherited methods

Comment: i have tried changing actionPreformed to actionPerformed, and still have an error